# Is it possible to sequentially chain Google DataPrep flows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataprep

I have quite a long set of transforms, which I'd like to break into modules (each in it's own flow). I can't see a way of chaining these, other than scheduling consecutive timeslots. Has anyone managed this, or do I need to build one massive flow?

Answer (score 1):

In your flow page, click on the three dots `...` near your recipe. In the menu, you have `Create Reference Dataset`. Once created, you will see a new logo under your recipe, you can then click on the menu and choose `Add to flow`